# digest returns the same value with different data

Tags: javascript, hash, sha256, webcrypto-api

I'm using Javascript Forge to get a digest for some data, right now the experiment is with different documents and the following lines of code always returns the same hash:

```
function obtainData() {
    getDocument(getHash);
}

function getDocument(callback) {
    var file = dInput.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e){
        var contents = e.target.result;
        var array = callback(contents)
        console.log(array.digest().toHex());
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}

function getHash(buffer) {
    digestHash = forge.md.sha256.create();
    digestHash.update(buffer);
    //always the same with different bytes everytime
    console.log(digestHash.digest().toHex());
    return digestHash;
}
```

why is this happening? Am I missing something?

Tried with different browsers and still the same digestHash value

Answer (score 2):

Forge library usually works with Uint8. converting content to Uint8Array should works properly

```
reader.onload = function(e){
    var contents = e.target.result;
    var  binary = arrayBufferToString(contents);
    var array = callback(binary)
    console.log(array.digest().toHex());
}


function arrayBufferToString( buffer ) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
    }
    return binary;
}
```

Using WebCryptographiApi is also a good solution

```js
function obtainData() {
  getDocument(getHash);
}

function arrayBufferToString( buffer ) {
  var binary = '';
  var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
  var len = bytes.byteLength;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
  }
  return binary;
}

function getDocument(callback) {
  var file = dInput.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e){
    var contents = e.target.result;
    var array = callback(contents)
    console.log(array.digest().toHex());
  }
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}

function getHash(buffer) {
  digestHash = forge.md.sha256.create();
  digestHash.update(arrayBufferToString(buffer));
  return digestHash;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/artjomb/96b970358e20410fa64daa2e844aeb0f/raw/5375e7171ef297d436d65b962149dcc0e1960b2b/forge_v0.6.39.min.js"></script>
<input id="dInput" type="file">
<button onclick="obtainData()">hash</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason all hash values are the same for different documents or data is that method that tries to digest always refers to the object that contains the data ([object Object]), so it will always get the same result. So, to circumvent this I decided to use webcrypto.

```
function getHash(buffer) {
    console.log(buffer);
    var crypto = window.crypto || window.msCrypto;
    var digestHash;

    var promise = crypto.subtle.digest({name:"SHA-256"},
    convertStringToArrayBufferView(buffer));

    promise.then(function (result) {
        digestHash = convertArrayBufferToHexadecimal(result);
        console.log(digestHash);
    });

    return digestHash;
}

function convertStringToArrayBufferView(str) {
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(str.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        bytes[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes;
}

function convertArrayBufferToHexadecimal(buffer) {
    var data_view = new DataView(buffer);
    var i, len, hex = '', c;
    for(i = 0, len = data_view.byteLength; i<len; i+=1){
        c = data_view.getUint8(i).toString(16);
        if(c.length < 2){
            c = '0' + c;
        }
        hex += c;
    }

    return hex;
}
```

I found this solution on http://qnimate.com/. There´s a section on Hashing with WebCrypto.

Answer (score 0):

Try scoping digestHash like so:

```
function getHash(buffer) {
    // in your post the below line is missing 'var'
    // without the below 'var' digestHash will be global
    var digestHash = forge.md.sha256.create(); 
    digestHash.update(buffer);
    //always the same with different bytes everytime
    console.log(digestHash.digest().toHex());
    return digestHash;
}
```

Comment: Put the 'var' keyword before the first 'digestHash' in your function. As you have it in your post digestHash is global and may be getting overwritten. I'll update my answer to highlight it it better.

Comment: nop, still the same hash, I made var digestHash and no change

Comment: Try putting a console.log( buffer ); as the first line in getHash and see if you are actually passing in seperate files or if somehow the same file is getting passed in. Other than that, I think I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: the hash always is on the object itself not the data that contains it